# wordpress : how to put an enter page?

Tags: wordpress

ive created an enter page for wordpress and what im wondering is how do i put it as the index page when the index page has the code to load wordpress? how and where do i place the enter page? thanks

Answer (score 3):

There's setting in [wordpress admin page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page) which doesn't involve manual setting in .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that splash pages are so very wrong... (the only defensible exception I can think of is for an adults only site that asks you if you are 18 or older), you could set it up as `index.html` and ensure your .htaccess has

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

Comment: i hate the idea if you ask me. its for a client and they want it. and its not an adult site.

Answer (score 0):

Things that you could do ...

1. Put the splash page on /index.html and put wordpress in /site/ (or something else innocuous); put a redirect on /index.html -> /site/ after the splash is done.
2. Put the splash page as a page named 'Splash' in Wordpress, with its own template.  In the Reading settings page, set the 'Front Page' as 'Splash'.  Redirect to the index page after the splash is done.
3. Put the splash page as a page named 'Splash' in Wordpress, with its own template.  Modify index.php in your theme to check for a cookie -- if the cookie isn't present, load the Splash page instead of processing the Wordpress Loop.  Once the splash page is done, set the cookie and redirect to the index page.

Answer (score 0):

A route that's worked for me is to bypass the WordPress core files and do everything from your theme folder. So, for example, in your theme folder (`WEBROOT/wp-content/themes/YOURTHEMEFOLDER`) add a home.php file, and in that file, add whatever code you'd like to use for that first page. By default, WordPress looks for a file named home.php, if it finds it, it will use it first, if it doesn't find it, it will use the index.php next. Since you'd like to use both, it will use home.php for your home page / site default page & then every other page can use the index.php page.

Also, there's other template files that WordPress will look towards before it displays the index.php page - for a detailed list / illustration of this go to http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy & scroll down a little.